# how to remove absolute disk path in django urls

Tags: django, url, path, disk

I use Django 3.1, and i get a trouble. who can tell me how to do. thanks.
My problem is my site path in linux Hard disk appeared in the admin url, like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/data/pysites/mysite.com/mysite/admin/

'/data/pysites/mysite.com/mysite/' is my linux disk path,
```

it appeared in the admin url,

```
I hope it is only ‘http://127.0.0.1/admin/’,
```

how can i remove it?

```
in vews.py, i print request.path is:
/data/pysites/xxx.com/mysite/play/ed160af7-5c98-4868-a679-2e86803e67d2/
i think the right path shuold be /play/ed160af7-5c98-4868-a679-2e86803e67d2/
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django's forum , a master KenWhitesell  pointed out the problem to me.

> You’re causing it by using the root-path parameter in your run command.

See the Daphne docs for Root Path, and the referenced docs for WSGI SCRIPT_NAME.

so i changed the run command, just remove  the --root-path parameter. it all right.

if you meet this problem too, i hope this can help to you.